# JavaScript not working in IE but in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I wrote a Internet page in vb.net , which has a method for creating a dynamic Javascript, which is inserted in the  
The javascript works in firefox but not on IE ... 
Does anyone have any idea to solve the problem?

tanks

this is the code:
ù

```
<script type="text/javascript">function mostraPILOTA(){
$("div#PILOTA").css("display", "block")
$("a#PILOTA").css("display", "block")
.css("visibility", "visible")
.css("background-color", "green")
$("div#Lotto01").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto02").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto03").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto04").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto05").css("display", "none")
 $("div#Lotto06").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto07").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto08").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto09_1").css("display", "none")
$("a#Lotto01").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto02").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto03").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto04").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto05").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto06").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto07").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto08").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto09_1").css("background-color", "blue")
}
function mostraLotto01(){
$("div#Lotto01").css("display", "block")
$("a#Lotto01").css("display", "block")
.css("visibility", "visible")
.css("background-color", "green")
 $("div#PILOTA").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto02").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto03").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto04").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto05").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto06").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto07").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto08").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto09_1").css("display", "none")
$("a#PILOTA").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto02").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto03").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto04").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto05").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto06").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto07").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto08").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto09_1").css("background-color", "blue")
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's not javascript

Comment: @adeneo: It does, buried in there somewhere, *generate* some JavaScript.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">function mostraPILOTA(){
$("div#PILOTA").css("display", "block"
$("a#PILOTA").css("display", "block")
.css("visibility", "visible")
.css("background-color", "green")
$("div#Lotto01").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto03").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto08").css("display", "none")
$("div#Lotto09_1").css("display", "none")
$("a#Lotto01").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto02").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto03").css("background-color", "blue")
$("a#Lotto06").css("background-color", "blue")

}

Comment: *"Does not work"* is not a useful problem description. What do you expect to happen, what happens instead, and why does that surprise you? Separately: What's the HTML this is acting one? What errors do you see in the web console? What happens when you single-step through the code using the debugger built into your browser?

Comment: Can you provide **JS Fiddle** ?

Comment: When i open the page the <div> ara not visible, but when a click the button the corrisponding <div> meke visible...I not have errors, but if I open the page in IE i see only the buttons and the javascript not works, but if I open the page on Firefox the javascript works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that you should simplify/parameterize your code, you seem to be using duplicate `id`s. That is, using the same `id` on different elements (*`a` and `div`*).

That is invalid in html and bound to create problems..

You will have to make your `id`s unique.

Comment: Ok i try to change the id...thanks